# Why is HH:mm 00:00 when year is included in JavaScript moment format?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, datetime-format

I want to format a time to 'DD-MM-yyyy HH:mm', but the 'HH:mm' part is unexpectedly 00:00.

In Node.js I have the following code using the moment library:

```
console.log(history.created_at)
console.log(moment(history.created_at).format('DD-MM-yyyy HH:mm'))
console.log(moment(history.created_at).format('DD-MM HH:mm'))
```

which e.g. gives the output:

```
2020-06-03 08:43:07.778+02
03-06-2020 00:00
03-06 08:43
```

As seen above, formatting with `'DD-MM-yyyy HH:mm'` gives invalid hours and minutes, but when I remove the year from the formatting string, i.e. `'DD-MM HH:mm'` the hours and minutes are correct.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

Comment: Note that "yyyy" isn't defined as a [format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/). "YYYY" is.

Comment: @deceze `y` is valid - `era year`

Comment: @Justinas Yes, but a quadruple "yyyy" appears largely undocumented.

Comment: yyyy is documented under [*Era Year related tokens*](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), it's effectively the same as YYYY for recent dates.

Comment: @RobG That's in the *parse* section though; apparently it behaves differently for displaying, perhaps it's buggy.

Comment: @deceze—or the documentation isn't up to date. It would be unusual to use the same token for different purposes when parsing and formatting.

Answer (score 3):

```js
const created_at = '2020-06-03 08:43:07.778+02'

console.log(
  moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm')
)
console.log(
  moment(created_at).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm')
)
console.log(
  moment(created_at).format('DD-MM-yyyy HH:mm')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

You should use `YYYY` instead `yyyy`

Comment: Ok thanks. I can see yyyy is era year. Shouldn't it work with HH:mm as well?